# My last question - how do I unsubscribe?

Tags: support, user-accounts

How do I unsubscribe from SE physics?
I have looked on my profile but can see no method.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999/

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/2632/2451

Comment: Have you decided to leave the site forever?

Comment: @Danu Yes. Already put in the request. This site is a serious waste of time for anyone who gets paid to do experimental physics. I also dislike the anti-engineering snobbishness shown by some moderators

Comment: Okay. I'm sorry you feel that way!

Comment: @DirkBruere If you delete yourself, you forever give up any possibility to make anything here better. Not this is the good solution, the best if you only stop to post anything - you can't be sure, when is the day coming as you will be able to use the site for some useful.

Comment: Bye Dirk. Sorry to see you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [contact us](https://physics.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of the page and choose the reason "I need to delete my user profile", then follow the instructions (if any) that you receive. It may take a few days for the request to be processed.

Reference: [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/263383) at Meta Stack Exchange.